# My Facebook cover photo is duplicated in an album. Can I merge the two pictures?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I uploaded a photo for my Facebook cover photo, but did not realize that the same photo had previously been uploaded in an album. Facebook didn't pick up on this, and now some people have liked the one in the album, while the majority have liked the cover photo. It is not a big problem, but I was wondering if I could merge the two so that the 'likes' are merged as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now there is no feature available to merge photos.

You can delete the duplicate pic but you will loss the likes and comments.